# Segmentation Fault in Rails App on OS X 10.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, segmentation-fault

I bought a Macbook Pro running OS X 10.8. I've installed `rvm` and `ruby` with this [guide](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/).

The installation was successful, but when I start the Rails app, or click 3-4 times on the pages in the app, I get a segmentation fault error.

[Here are my errors.](https://gist.github.com/4444214)

There are no reports in `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter` or `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter` about the crashes.

My `rvm` version is `1.17.6`, and 
Ruby version `1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]` with Rails 3.2.8.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you clicking randomly on pages in the app, or actually sending data between the browser and Rails? If randomly and no data is being sent to Rails, it's not a Ruby or Rails problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3-p362 seems to be rather prone to segfaults as seen [several times on Travis-CI](https://twitter.com/travisci/status/285014980363943937).

You should use an older patch release, e.g. 1.9.3-p327 which worked just fine for me.

Edit: The current versions of 1.9.3 (1.9.3-p392 as of this update) work fine too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've installed this version and no segfaults.